# Form validation and error messages not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm currently working on several forms for an app and chose to use **Material UI** and **React Hook Forms** to build them. The basic functions are working, which means I can only proceed when all required inputs are filled and I'm getting the desired data.

Unfortunately I'm not able to use the form validation or display of error messages that comes with **React Hook Form**. It is still using the **Material UI** validation, even though I followed along to the documentation as close as possible.

Here's what I want to be able to do:

- define the min and max length of an input
- enter RegEx patterns for password inputs
- show the neat looking error messages of **React Hook Form**

Some of the logic is working, some is not. Can you help me figure out why? Thank you in advance!

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// COMPONENTS
import Button from '../01-atoms/inputs/Button';
import Textfield from '../01-atoms/inputs/Textfield';

// MATERIAL UI - CORE
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

// MATERIAL UI - ICONS
import LockSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockSharp';
import PersonAddSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PersonAddSharp';

export default function SignUp({ i18n, submitSignUpData }) {

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
      <Fade in>
        <Paper elevation={3}>
          <Typography align='center' gutterBottom variant='h5'>
            {i18n.sign_up.page_title}
          </Typography>

          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitSignUpData)}>
            <Grid container spacing={1}>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Controller
                  // This is not working:
                  rules={register({
                    required: true,
                    minLength: 8,
                  })}
                  // But this is:
                  required
                  as={Textfield}
                  name='newPassword'
                  control={control}
                  defaultValue=''
                  fullWidth
                  label={i18n.login.password_placeholder}
                  variant='outlined'
                  type='password'
                  InputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position='end'>
                        <LockSharpIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
                {errors.newPassword && 'Your input is required!'}
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Button
                  fullWidth
                  content={i18n.sign_up.get_started_button}
                  variant='contained'
                  color='secondary'
                  type='submit'
                  endIcon={<PersonAddSharpIcon />}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
          <Link to='/log-in'>
            <Typography>{i18n.login.login_button}</Typography>
          </Link>
        </Paper>
      </Fade>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem. Also, you say "Some of the logic is working, some is not." Please clarify exactly which logic is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using controller why don't you use **TextField** of Material UI. I have something like this in my code.

```
    <TextField
      name="newPassword"
      label="Password"
      inputRef={register({ required: true, minLength: 8 })}
      defaultValue=''
    />
    {
      errors.newPassword &&
      <ErrorText>
        {errors.newPassword.type === "required" ?
          'Password is required.' :
          `Min character limit for Password is 8.`}
      </ErrorText>
    }
```